# Prevent TableView from scrolling when sidebar is active

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, swift

I have a sidebar in an `UITableView` which will display after a long press on a cell. The sidebar has some custom buttons for more functionality.

[image: SideView]

If the user tab on the `UITableView`, I will check for the location of the point. If it is outside of the sidebar, then I will close it.

The problem here is, if the user try to scroll (its about 100 rows here) the sidebar stays on the exact place. So my goal is to prevent the user from scrolling on the table as long the sideview is present. (I will also highlight the selected row later.)

I created a `UIGestureRecognizer`:

```
    tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "handleTap:")
    view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture!)
```

And check the location:

```
func handleTap(recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer){

    let location = recognizer.locationInView(view)
        if !CGRectContainsPoint(contentView.frame, location){
    // dismiss
}
```

I have a delegate which shows me if the sideview is present, but if I try to set:

```
tableView.userInteractionEnabled = false
```

I am unable to click on the sideview, so all user interactions are disabled.

Is there a way to disable only scrolling?

Comment: tableView.scrollEnabled = NO;

Comment: That was quick, thanks! I overlook that in the docs.

Comment: does it work for you?

Comment: Yes, it works as expected. I was so totally fixed on try to disabling all userInteractions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So simple just write this

```
tableView.scrollEnabled = NO;
```